# Gas Boiler Electric Flow Chart

Tags: boiler

I am looking for a flow chart that shows what happens when a gas fired hot water boiler thermostat calls for heat  the power goes from the thermostat to the ? and then to the ? and so on

Comment: @jwh20 A hot water boiler is a form of home heating so in general it would have a pump to circulate the water through pipes and heat the house. Much different use-case compared to water heaters. You can hover over the "boiler" tag for more info or see https://diy.stackexchange.com/tags/boiler/info

Comment: My misunderstanding...  Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Assuming that you have a pretty standard old-style boiler then this PDF should help to answer all of your questions. https://uticaboilers.com/sites/default/files/240011125%20UTICA%20BOILERS%20MGC%20IOM%20REV.%20C.pdf